Clover Oauth2.0 v2 - Is there a way to call the authorize in v2 & get authCode programmatically - Oauth v2
In Oauth2.0, when we call the v2/authorize api it redirects to the site URL. Is there a way not to redirect it to the site URL but get the authCode like we used to get in legacy version. In Oauth2.0 token we need a auth code which comes from this authorize redirect to uri. Any way of calling that API and get the code - I m not able to find anything on it. Any help would be highly appreciated

Hi, just want an update. did you got a workaround for this?

@carlo It is mandatory to redirect the merchants to the site URL. You will have to handle that in your website that when a merchant is still on v1 - redirect it to clover where they login to get the authCode. I
